# Symlink между двумя контейнерами в volumes

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

У меня есть два контейнера с php и nginx соответственно. К обоим контейнерам подключается `volumes` с проектом, в проекте есть директории которые связаны симлинками.
Проблема в том, что докер не умеет связывать симлинки из `volumes` между контейнерами.

Пример:

```
/my_project     # Корень проекта
    /web
        /images # Симлинк на my_project/images (не будет работать в docker контейнере)
    /web_admin
        /images # Симлинк на my_project/images (не будет работать в docker контейнере)
    /images
docker-compose.yml

# Конфигурация docker-compose
services:
    nginx:
        ...
        volumes:
            # Подключение тома my_project к nginx-контейнеру
            - ./my_project:/var/www 
    php:
        ...
        volumes:
            # Подключение тома my_project к php-контейнеру
            - ./my_project:/var/www
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , добавил пример

Comment: указывайте [относительный путь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/317380/178576) при создании symlink.